# Dynamically added hintLabel on mat-form-field only becomes visible after component receives focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two select boxes. When a value is chosen in the first select box, a call to the server is made to populate the second select box. Since this second call takes ~10 seconds for reasons outside of my control, I want to show a hint that says something like "Please wait, fetching XYZ from server."

I've got an event handler set up on the first select box for the select change event, and it's correctly setting the hint on the second box. However the second box doesn't *show* the hint until it receives focus. (If I try to put the hint on the first box, it immediately shows the hint because it already has focus.)

I'm using Angular CLI 7.0.2, Angular 7.0.0, and node 8.11.1.

Component ts:

```
@ViewChild("otherSelect")
secondSelect: MatFormField;

onFirstThingSelect(event: MatSelectChange ) {
 this.secondSelect.hintLabel = "Please wait, loading...";
 // expensive/slow call to populate secondSelect goes here
}
```

Component html:

```
<mat-form-field #firstSelect>
  <mat-select placeholder="First Thing" (selectionChange)="onFirstThingSelect($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let first of firstThings$ | async" [value]="first">
      {{first}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-md-4" #otherSelect>
  <mat-select placeholder="Second Thing">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let second of secondThings$ | async" [value]="second">
      {{second}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjd8m-qm8mxp

Clearly this isn't what the matHint (or hintLabel) was originally indended for. But, how can I cause the hint to show against the second select after populating the first? Must I add a ViewChild for the actual second select dropdown and force focus onto it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Marshal -- All of the alternative solutions listed below work.

Comment: Good information for anyone reviewing your question in the future. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to dynamically set the `hintLabel` @Input, bind it to a variable and dynamically set the variable content:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-4" [hintLabel]="hintLabel">
  <mat-select placeholder="Second Thing">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let second of secondThings$ | async" [value]="second">
      {{second}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


hintLabel = '';

onFirstThingSelect(event: MatSelectChange ) {
  this.hintLabel = "I should become visible when First Thing is selected.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the "placeHolder".
You can use "tap" in the second thing to show different values. If this.secondThing return a null value is because is loading data, else you show a message like "Select Option".

see [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjd8m-5ikwxg?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts)

The important part is:

```
this.secondThings$ = this._seconds.asObservable().pipe(tap((res) => {
      if (!res)
        this.secondPlaceHolder.placeHolder = "Loadding data...";
      else
        this.secondPlaceHolder.placeholder = "Select Option.";

    }))
```

When a change happens, first send a null

```
  onFirstThingSelect(event: MatSelectChange) {
    this._seconds.next(null); //<--send a null before loading the data
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._seconds.next(["AA", "BB", "CC"]);
    }, 2000)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could statically assign the mat-hint in your template and display using a boolean variable rather than the mat-form-field hint... this way you can display the hint and hide it programmatically without focus.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjd8m-przarn?embed=1&file=app/form-field-overview-example.html